# What construct do I use to guarantee 100 tasks are running in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was trying to create an integration test for my service where 100 clients would connect, login, send  request, and log all responses for some configurable amount of time.

I was build a class for the client using async sockets and it works fine. I started them all up using Task and Task.Factory, sent the login, and posted receives every time I got data, until the time expired and then I called shutdown on them.

It seems these never really run in parallel. Sometimes  I might get 35ish running at once, sometimes a little more. I assume the task scheduler is running them when it seems fit rather than all at once.

Now I understand that I cannot truly have 100 threads running simultaneous, but I want to guarantee that all 100 are started and that the OS is context switching back and forth attempting to execute them all.

In the end, I want to simulate a large number of clients connected to my service all getting a stream of data.

What construct do I use if Task does not work?

Current Attempt:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IntegrationTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string       server            = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"];
            int          port              = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"]);
            int          numClients        = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["numberOfClients"]);
            TimeSpan     clientLifetime    = TimeSpan.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientLifetime"]);
            TimeSpan     timeout           = TimeSpan.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["timeout"]);
            TimeSpan     reconnectInterval = TimeSpan.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reconnectInterval"]);
            List<string> clientIds         = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("clientIds") as List<string>;

            try
            {
                // SNIP configure logging

                // Create the specified number of clients, to carry out test operations, each on their own threads
                Task[] tasks = new Task[numClients];
                for(int count = 0; count < numClients; ++count)
                {
                    var index = count;
                    tasks[count] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                // Reuse client Ids, if there are more clients then clientIds.
                                // Keep in mind that tasks are not necessarily started in the order they were created in this loop.
                                // We may see client id 1 be assigned client id 2 if another client was started before it, but we
                                // are using all clientIds
                                string clientId = null;
                                if (numClients < clientIds.Count)
                                {
                                    clientId = clientIds[index];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    clientId = clientIds[index % clientIds.Count];
                                }

                                // Create the actual client
                                Client client = new Client(server, port, clientId, timeout, reconnectInterval);
                                client.Startup();

                                // Will make an sync request issue a recv.
                                // Everytime we get a reponse, it will be logged and another recv will be posted.
                                // This will continue until shutdown is called
                                client.MakeRequest(symbol);

                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(clientLifetime);

                                client.Shutdown();
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                // SNIP - Log it
                            }
                        });
                }
                Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // SNIP - Log it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the tasks long enough so that when you run the 100th, the 1st one is still running?

Comment: I made the length of time configurable. I tried running it for 30 minutes and never saw all 100 going at once in my service logs.

Comment: Why do you care whether or not all 100 clients are running at the exact same time?  What you really care about is overall execution time/throughput.  Having too many things running in parallel can actually make performance *worse* as the context switching consumes a significant percentage of processing time.

Comment: Run your client software on more than one machine.

Comment: Internally the TPL will decide how many threads.  You can override....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075320/using-tpl-how-do-i-set-a-max-threadpool-size, but be aware too many threads can cause issues.  You should experiment to find the sweet spot on your hardware and then create X clients to simulate load.  One machine may not be enough to service 100 clients.

Comment: If you want to guarantee there are 100 threads, use `Thread` rather than `Task`.  It's the only way to guarantee it.  Do note that operating systems can have limits on the number of threads, and too many threads per core can have the app spend so much time context switching it doesn't have time to actually run.

Comment: 25 threads per core might be OK (i.e. 4 cores) but things get questionable at 50 or more threads per core.  Also, make sure there is a `Thread.Sleep(1);` in the loop to prevent 100 threads from melting your CPU for no reason.

Comment: @17-26 I want to simulate load on my service. The performance of clients is not something I care about at all. They aren't doing anything anyway. They just issue a request and recv..

Comment: As a matter of terminology, [concurrency isn't the same as parallel](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/190725/3733). You can't have more parallelism than you have number of CPU cores, but you can have more concurrent tasks than the number of CPU using either preemptive or cooperative task switching.

Comment: Try search for stress-testing or load-testing tools for C#. These will open many connections at a time without subjecting to the assumption of one thread / one task per client connection.

Comment: I think the accepted answer here is wrong. your use of thread.sleep in a task is a bug, and you don't show where you are logging. see my answer

Comment: You can have 100 pseudo-parallel clients active in just 1 thread: An event loop thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tasks and Threads exist for different purposes.  Tasks are intended to be short running things which need to be run in the background.  Threads represent an operating resource for concurrent execution.

Internally, the TaskManager uses a Thread pool so that it can reuse threads to process more tasks.  Threads are expensive to set up and tear down so they don't work well for the purpose that Tasks were created.  While you can influence the number of threads available to the task manager, it is still responsible for dishing out the work to the threads.

**Guaranteeing X Number of Concurrent Clients**

The only way to guarantee this is to use `Thread` instead of `Task`.  If you were to restructure your code a bit you could handle your simultaneous clients like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace IntegrationTests
{
    private static string server;
    private static int port;
    private static TimeSpan clientLifetime;
    private static TimeSpan timeout;
    private static TimeSpan reconnectInterval;
    private static List<string> clientIds;
    private static Barrier barrier;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int          numClients        = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["numberOfClients"]);
            server            = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"];
            port              = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"]);
            clientLifetime    = TimeSpan.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientLifetime"]);
            timeout           = TimeSpan.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["timeout"]);
            reconnectInterval = TimeSpan.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reconnectInterval"]);
            clientIds         = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("clientIds") as List<string>;
            barrier           = new Barrier(numClients + 1);

            try
            {
                // SNIP configure logging

                // Create the specified number of clients, to carry out test operations, each on their own threads
                Thread[] threads= new Thread[numClients];
                for(int count = 0; count < numClients; ++count)
                {
                    var index = count;
                    threads[count] = new Thread();
                    threads[count].Name = $"Client {count}"; // for debugging
                    threads[count].Start(RunClient);
                }

                // We loose the convenience of awaiting all tasks,
                // but use a thread barrier to block this thread until all the others are done.
                barrier.SignalAndWait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // SNIP - Log it
            }
        }

        private void RunClient()
        {
            try
            {
                // Reuse client Ids, if there are more clients then clientIds.
                // Keep in mind that tasks are not necessarily started in the order they were created in this loop.
                // We may see client id 1 be assigned client id 2 if another client was started before it, but we
                // are using all clientIds
                string clientId = null;
                if (numClients < clientIds.Count)
                {
                    clientId = clientIds[index];
                }
                else
                {
                    clientId = clientIds[index % clientIds.Count];
                }

                // Create the actual client
                Client client = new Client(server, port, clientId, timeout, reconnectInterval);
                client.Startup();

                // Will make an sync request issue a recv.
                // Everytime we get a reponse, it will be logged and another recv will be posted.
                // This will continue until shutdown is called
                client.MakeRequest(symbol);

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(clientLifetime);

                client.Shutdown();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                // SNIP - Log it
            }
            finally
            {
                barrier.SignalAndWait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure about this? I don't think it makes any difference whether you start the thread manually or let the thread pool handle it.

Comment: @Ewan, I am positive about this.  If you want a _guarantee_ that you have _n_ number of threads, you have to manually start _n_ number of threads.  The threadpool can run out, and tasks are not threads.  They are meant to be lightweight short running tasks that run on threads.

Comment: true, but the OP isnt hitting a limit to concurrent tasks, its just a misuse of thread.sleep

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a problem with your test.

I've used similar code for (basic) load testing and seen well over 100 concurrent tasks.

I would guess there is a problem with the way you are logging. Are you simply measuring the number of concurrent connections your server can handle?

For instance, the below code will count up to 1000.

However, notice the difference if we replace Task.Delay with Thread.Sleep. This breaks the app because more than one task runs on the same thread.

Now, if we *also* change the task.Add to :

```
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => Work(),TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
```

The code works again, as it knows to create the new tasks on new threads

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        volatile int count = 0;
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task TestMethod1()
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for(int i = 0;i<1000;i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(Work());
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
            Debug.WriteLine("finished");
        }

        async Task Work()
        {
            count++;
            Debug.WriteLine(count);
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            Debug.WriteLine(count);
            count--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: True that `Task.Delay()` is a different mechanism.  Essentially it allows the same thread to be re-used for another task while this one goes to sleep.  Do note that a task that is running can delay the wake up time if your thread pool is saturated so you shouldn't assume that the time you give it is in any way accurate.